# Python and variables

Tags: python, bash, curl

I am new to python and researched a log (probably the wrong way) and now decided to ask:

I have a bash script, which outputs two values. In a python script I invoke this this script by

```
subprocess.Popen(...skript details...)
(output, err) = p.communicate()
p_status = p.wait()
print "Command output : ", output
print "Command exit status/return code : ", p_status
value1, value2 = output.split(' ',1)
```

If I now add

```
print value1
```

I get what I expect (a numeric value).

Now I got some code from github to post data within a python script using curl. This builds the body like

```
body='{"mode":"async", "messageType":"1", "messages":[{"Name of Value1":value1, "Name of Value2":value2}]}'
```

However, what gets posted is the text "value1" and "value2" and not the actual values of the variables. I tried a lot of masking here but could not get any valuable result.
Thx in advance

Comment: "temp" and "humid"?  No variables or values by those names appear in any of the code you posted.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: check, these are actually values 1 and 2... corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correct, you need string formatting.

```
body='{"mode":"async", "messageType":"1", "messages":[{"Name of Value1":{0}]}'.format(value1)
```

It is done by built in [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function.

Here is what you need to do for your example:

```
>>> humidity = 99

>>> temp = 100

>>> print "[ {{ temperature: {0}, humidity: {1} }} ]".format(temp, humidity)

[ { temperature: 100, humidity: 99 } ]
```

Note: to escape {} from formatting use double braces {{}} around.

Comment: Thx, I think that's not exactly, what I need. Putting it different: value 1 is humidity, e.g. 57.5 . I need something like [{"Humidity":57.5}]

Comment: what do you have inside value1 variable, and what do you want to have inside your body string?

Comment: Value1 is called `Humidity` and contains a numeric value like `57.5`. From my body string I get the following posted: {"Humidity": humid} (first is correct, but second is wrong, should be the numeric contents of the variable).

Comment: what is printed from `print value1`?

Comment: 57.5. Let's look at the original code without alienation: I have defined variables with: `humid, temp = output.split(' ',1)` and print shows correct values. Body end part is  `"messages":[{"temperature":temp, "humidity":humid}]}'` and outputs temperature:temp,humidity:humid instead of desired temperature:75.4,humid:57.5

Comment: Where would you want to get it like dict, if you don't have it from output? I mean, you get only numeric value into your value. So there is no way to get 'Name of value1' if you will not pass it into you value1, and than extract into body.

Comment: that mean that you are not using format function, or you get string values into your variables for some reason

Comment: I am sorry my English is too bad, i believe we are talking about different things. The first parts like "temperature" and "humidity" are text descriptions - these are okay and are not the problem. The second parts like "temp" and "humid" are defined in the variables and contain a numeric value, and that is what I want to have here - a reference to these variables, but instead I get only their name printed.

Comment: your last comment is because there is no `format` used. You are wrapping python variables `temp` and `humid` insitde string, and they are interpreted as strings. Use `format`

Comment: @Steffen please heck - I have updated answer. Is it what you mean?

Comment: great, thanks a lot. The double braces helped a lot :-)